# Crash report.. any clue where to look for?

Tags: ios, crash

I'm receiving many iOS crash reports that look like copied below... Does anyone have any clue where to look for a resolution? It seems the crash occurs during launch, but it is not clear at all which method is responsible for it. I can also not reproduce it..
Thanks!

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         XXXXXX [499]
Path:            /Users/USER/XXXX.app/XXXX
Identifier:      XXXXXXX
Version:         16.1
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-10-26T00:14:55Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x3a3d41fc
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3a3d41fc ___pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3a384ffd _abort + 77
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x396b3cd7 abort_message + 75
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x396cc6e5 default_terminate_handler() + 253
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39e15921 _objc_terminate() + 193
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x396ca1c7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x396c9d2d ___cxa_increment_exception_refcount + 1
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39e157f7 _objc_exception_rethrow + 43
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2f970d5d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 641
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2f970acb _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
10  GraphicsServices                    0x34691283 _GSEventRunModal + 139
11  UIKit                               0x32212a41 _UIApplicationMain + 1137
12  XXXXXXX                             0x000829d7 main (main.m:55)
```

Comment: try adding exception breakpoint!

Comment: drag this to xcode it just decrypt for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that a Objective-C exception was thrown, caught, and then re-thrown. The original stacktrace is then lost unless you saved/logged it where you caught it.

Look for any place in your code where you catch Objective-C exceptions, and also look in any third party frameworks you might use.

Of course, first try to reproduce the problem in a debugger, where you set a breakpoint on all exceptions (click the little '+' icon down to the left in the Breakpoint tab in Xcode).